error in cypress typescript cucumber setup only when if there is parameter in feature file
I have installed a  cypress under my angular repository where I have configured cucumber using @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor for processing the feature file. feature file executes well if i do not have passed any parameter but it gives below error when i pass a parameter as below in then statement.
feature file:
Feature: Google Launch
As a user
I want to launch the Google homepage
So that I can access its services
  Scenario: Open Google homepage
    Given I open the Google homepage
    Then I should see the Google "good morning"

Step definition file:
import {Given, Then} from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';

Given('I open the Google homepage', () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.google.com');
});

Then('I should see the Google {string}', (val:any) => {
  cy.log("message from google "+ val)
  cy.get('img[alt="Googlex"]').should('be.visible');
});

Error :
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:45)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| });
| 
> Then('I should see the Google {string}', (val:any) => {
|   cy.log("message from google "+ val)
|   cy.get('img[alt="Googlex"]').should('be.visible');
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (-frontend\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:212:23)

cypress.config.ts:
import {defineConfig} from 'cypress'

const webpack = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.feature$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
              options: config,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
})
);

 return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    'baseUrl': 'http://localhost:4200',
    specPattern: ["**/e2e/**/*.feature"],
    setupNodeEvents
  },
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'angular',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
    specPattern: '**/*.cy.ts'
}
 })

package.json:
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": { "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/acceptance-test/step-definition/*.step.cy.ts"}
tsconfig inside cypress folder:
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": [
      "cypress"
    ]
  }
}

packag.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.0",
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^20.0.1",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^2.5.1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/cypress": "^0.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "cypress": "^13.6.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2"
  }

Can someone tell me if I am missing anything here to consider the feature file parameter ?
